# helm ls command throws Error: forwarding ports:

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I see this error while doing `helm ls` command. At least 8 out of 10 runs will fail with below error.

```
Ambikas-MacBook-Pro-2:~ ambikanair$ helm ls
Error: forwarding ports: error upgrading connection: error dialing backend: dial tcp 10.184.253.159:10250: i/o timeout
Ambikas-MacBook-Pro-2:~ ambikanair$
```

I saw many related issues when I searched in google but nothing seems to fix my problem.
I noted that the issue is seen on a new cluster but If I take an existing one, it works well.

Comment: Check connectivity between Helm host and Kubernetes master using ping or telnet
Also, the port should be 6443 and not 10250, check again